# Getting issue in WebSecurity class for version 3.1.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, h2-console

I am using spring boot version 3.1.4 with Java-17 and spring-cloud.version - 2022.0.4 
and created below method

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors(cors -> {})
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users")
                    .access(new WebExpressionAuthorizationManager(
                            "hasIpAddress('" + environment.getProperty("gateway.ip") + "')"))
                    .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll())
            .sessionManagement((session) -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

    http.headers((headers) -> headers.frameOptions((frameOptions) -> frameOptions.sameOrigin()));

    return http.build();
}
```

Getting below issue

```
This is because there is more than one mappable servlet in your servlet context: {org.h2.server.web.JakartaWebServlet=[/h2-console/*], org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=[/]}.

For each MvcRequestMatcher, call MvcRequestMatcher#setServletPath to indicate the servlet path.
```

Here is full log of issue

```
2023-09-26T12:39:19.609+05:30  WARN 43222 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'configure' defined in class path resource [com/appsdeveloperblog/photoapp/api/users/security/WebSecurity.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'configure' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).

This is because there is more than one mappable servlet in your servlet context: {org.h2.server.web.JakartaWebServlet=[/h2-console/*], org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=[/]}.

For each MvcRequestMatcher, call MvcRequestMatcher#setServletPath to indicate the servlet path.
2023-09-26T12:39:19.611+05:30  INFO 43222 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-09-26T12:39:19.846+05:30  WARN 43222 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-214]
2023-09-26T12:39:19.847+05:30  INFO 43222 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-09-26T12:39:19.851+05:30  INFO 43222 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-09-26T12:39:19.863+05:30  INFO 43222 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-09-26T12:39:19.903+05:30  INFO 43222 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-09-26T12:39:19.964+05:30 ERROR 43222 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'configure' defined in class path resource [com/appsdeveloperblog/photoapp/api/users/security/WebSecurity.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'configure' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).

This is because there is more than one mappable servlet in your servlet context: {org.h2.server.web.JakartaWebServlet=[/h2-console/*], org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=[/]}.

For each MvcRequestMatcher, call MvcRequestMatcher#setServletPath to indicate the servlet path.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:875) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:828) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:492) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at com.appsdeveloperblog.photoapp.api.users.PhotoAppApiUsersApplication.main(PhotoAppApiUsersApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configure' defined in class path resource [com/appsdeveloperblog/photoapp/api/users/security/WebSecurity.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'configure' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).

This is because there is more than one mappable servlet in your servlet context: {org.h2.server.web.JakartaWebServlet=[/h2-console/*], org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=[/]}.

For each MvcRequestMatcher, call MvcRequestMatcher#setServletPath to indicate the servlet path.
```

can you please help me to resolve this issue
Thanks in advance

Comment: Since Spring Boot 3.1.x, if you have multiple servlets (which is the case if you add the H2 console), you have to explicitly say which servlet the request matcher should be applied to. Since the H2 console is commonly used, Spring provided a [`PathRequest.toH2Console()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/PathRequest.html#toH2Console()) matcher. Read more about how to use it in the duplicate.